# Run the flask in production environment using waitress

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I am using the following link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51025893/flask-at-first-run-do-not-use-the-development-server-in-a-production-environment) to set up the flask running but when I am running I am getting the 500 internal server. Now I have to run the flask in the production environment how do I do that using waitress.

Comment: Refer this answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/52093761/12130775

Comment: _Now I have to run the flask in the production environment how do I do that using waitress._ That's quite a broad question, see [ask] and [help/on-topic].