# Waitress serve takes too long to run flask server

Tags: python, flask, waitress

I am trying to run a flask app with waitress serve, but when i call "python app.py" nothing happens (i waited 2 minutes then ctrl+c). When i run flask with app.run() everything works normally. Some help would be appreciated

```py
import Flask
from waitress import serve

app=Flask(__name__)
<My code>
if __name__ == "__main__":
  serve(app,port="8080",host="0.0.0.0")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serving Flask app with waitress on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045911/serving-flask-app-with-waitress-on-windows)

Comment: There are multiple WSGI solutions, see e.g. https://quintagroup.com/cms/python/web-server Try other services. If they don't work your flask app may not be compatible with them. You are running multiple instances of the flask app and if they access the same file, use the same login or service etc. it can fail. Furthermore you should be showing the full traceback error or any logs.

Comment: @noah1400 I have already tried that and the powershell does nothing until I CTRL+C. On the other hand, when i write ```waitress-serve --host 127.0.0.1 "app:app"
``` everything works.

Comment: The shell shows nothing but the server still starts. If you run it on `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a method called `create_app()` for example which returns the Flask object.
You can add a route if you wish.

```py
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world():
      return 'Hello World!'
    return app
```

if your file is called `app.py`
run the following command.

```
waitress-serve --port 8080 --call "app:create_app"
```

Output:

```
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://0.0.0.0:8080
```

## Edit

---

If you really want to do it with `waitress.serve()` you can do this. For some reason this only works on localhost (127.0.0.1)

With your code **the server starts and is accessable** (the only thing you need are some routes) the only thing that is missing is terminal output.

You can activate logging like this:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('waitress')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

This causes the output:

```
INFO:waitress:Serving on http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

If you want to see every request:
install paste `pip install paste` and use `TransLogger`

```py
from paste.translogger import TransLogger
# modify serve function
serve(TransLogger(app, setup_console_handler=False), host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

This causes the following output on every request.

```
INFO:wsgi:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2022:15:40:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Of course this depends on your browser.

Full code:

```py
from flask import Flask
from waitress import serve
from paste.translogger import TransLogger
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('waitress')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
  return 'Hello World!'


serve(TransLogger(app, setup_console_handler=False), host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)
```

Comment: That works, but i would prefer to run python app.py in order for the server to start. And when I use serve() from waitress it does not work for some reason.

Comment: @Matias But the Server starts? There's just no output!?

Comment: @Matias I made some changes

Comment: I am so dumb lol, after running the code I was checking port 5000 instead of 8080 that's why i thought it was not working. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: I am glad. I was already wondering because everything worked for me :)